# How to embed PHP next to an HTML attribute

Tags: php, html

Here's a simple $64,000.00 question for everyone.

UPDATE: this is a PHP page... not a .html page...

I have a tag on an HTML page, basically I have something like this:

```
<td id="data">

... some other stuff

</td>
```

What I NEED to do is capture the PHP variable for the "ID" coming from the database and place it NEXT TO the "data" value in the ID attribute like this:.

```
<td id="data<?php echo $row_listNoticeboard['id']; ?>">

... some other stuff

</td>
```

But Netbeans 7.4 gives me an error stating:

---

Bad value "data" for attribute "id" on element "div": An ID must not contain whitespace.
Syntax of id:
An ID consists of at least one character but must not contain any whitespace.

From line 76, column 29; to line 76, column 152

### (Rule Category: Attributes)

So in Classic ASP I'd simply do it like this and have been over the years:

```
<td id="data<% response.write('id') %>">

.... some other stuff

</td>
```

Thanks

Comment: Will you be sending payment via paypal? money order? or??? $64000 is a lot for paypal I think. Might raise some red flags.

Comment: It's a little "yoke" from the 70s TV show, the $64,000.00 Question... :-).  A little "IT" humor never hurt anyone.

Comment: What happened to the other answers?? This actually worked:  <td id="data<?=$row_listNoticeboard['id'];?>".  It's weird but the first two answers are gone!

Comment: I got the joke. I was making one back. on the internet everything is sarcasm.

Answer (score 1):

Its a netbeans [bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=202029).

NetBeans HTML validator doesn't support embedded PHP code, so it is trying to validate your PHP code as a part of the HTML- which is of-course not.

Just `disable the HTML error checking` - you'll find it by clicking on the error bulb on left and this will fix it.